# How to do a "Corner Stamp" with Masonry Views?

Tags: views, javascript

I am building a jQuery Masonry based website, and have content listed as responsive Masonry bricks thorugh Masonry Views.

I need to be able to insert a so called "Corner Stamp" (a static right corner element) in the views results, so that the results wraps around the corner stamp, as described here: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/corner-stamp.html

In my case the corner stamp will be a unique View or Block with navigational features.

My question is:
How can I insert the corner stamp into a result set listed with Masonry Views?

Is this possible through Masonry Views (possibly with a template), or should I use jQuery Masonry without the module somehow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please link "Masonry Views" to its module's page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a thread in which considerable progress has been made: http://drupal.org/node/1988588#comment-7411276